# What can a girl do if her in-laws don't allow her to wear the hijab?

Tags: nikah, hijab

Veil is an important thing for Muslims girls in Islam.

My friend is suffering a problem which is related to the veil(Hijab). She used to wear Hijab from her school life but after marriage her in laws (including her husband) do not allow to wear the veil.

**What should she do? Does she argue and protest with her in laws or stay patient and follow their wishes?**

Comment: Islam does not mandate obedience to in-laws and especially not if it goes against Allah's commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to start off with arguments and protests, it is possible that her in-laws may be ignorant of Islamic teachings. She may try to explain to them the significance of Hijab with evidence e.g. from the Quran [Surah al-Ahzab verse 59](https://quran.com/33/59) and [Surah al-Ahzab verse 53](https://quran.com/33/53) and [Surah an-Nur verse 31](https://quran.com/24/31) and the tafsirs of these, and [the hadith of Asma](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/34/85) etc.